# How can I integrate ML model with Elasticsearch

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, machine-learning, nlp

I am working on a digital library management system. This library has millions of ebooks and its metadata is indexed in Elasticsearch (ES). My job is to create an interface where users can search a book with its metadata and then I can show the most relevant results.

Metadata have a title, abstract of each chapter, important topics, author name, publication year, page number and so on. These are indexed in ES.

I have created an ML model that identifies in which field it needs to make a query for example if the text is author name it makes a query to search in the author field or if it is publisher name then it searches in the publisher field. If it is a mix of multi-field then it searches in multiple fields.

I am hosting my ML code in a separate server where queries are being built in runtime and then I am doing `HTTPS POST` to Elasticsearch as follows. 
[image]
All these are working great without any problem. I am getting the desired result. **But I am curious to know if there is any way I can host or merge my ML code with Elasticsearch**. I want to remove **ML Flask Server**, I mean to say that I want to use the ML model with the ES server without flask server for hosting.

I want something like this
[image]

Is it possible to host or integrate my ML model with the AWS Elasticsearch service?